# Android cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times before but none of the solutions have worked for me. This is my code:

```
public class reminderDAO extends dbManager{



public reminderDAO(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


// Adding new reminder
public void addReminder(Reminder reminder) {
    //dbm.gettingWritable(values);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(getKEY_DATE(), reminder.getReminderDate());
    values.put(getKEY_TITLE(), reminder.getReminderTitle());
    values.put(getKEY_DESC(), reminder.getReminderDescription());
    values.put(getKEY_TIME(), reminder.getReminderTime());


    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(getDATABASE_TABLE(), null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public List<Reminder> getAllReminders(ListView lv) {



    ArrayList<Reminder> reminderList = new ArrayList<Reminder>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + getDATABASE_TABLE();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();



    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Reminder r = new Reminder();

            r.setReminderDate(cursor.getString(0));
            r.setReminderTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            r.setReminderDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            r.setReminderTime(cursor.getString(3));
            // Adding reminder to list
            reminderList.add(r);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Reminder> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Reminder>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            reminderList );

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    // return reminder list
    return reminderList;
}
}
```

I've got a feeling it is to do with 'this' inside the arrayAdapter. I have tried getActivity(), this.getActivity(), reminderDAO.this.getActivity(), MainActivity.this and reminderDAO.this.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: just a side node: Take care about the java code conventions. Class names should always start UpperCase: ReminderDao and DbManager is a better naming.

Comment: Ok thanks, noted. Any idea about the error I'm getting?

Comment: Did you tried `context`?

Comment: Just tried that there and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: what does the IDE complains about? what is the error message?

Comment: Ah wait, it compiles now with    context but I'm getting a null pointer exception on the ArrayAdapter when I run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Context variable in your class. and assign it from the constructor parameter.

```
private Context context;

public reminderDAO(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    super(context);
}
```

Then use this variable to pass to the `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<Reminder> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Reminder>(
            this.context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            reminderList );
```